# web3.js client library for PolkaDot

Tags: blockchain, web3js, polkadot

web3.js is 1 of 2 client libraries for connecting to Ethereum-compatible blockchain.
https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js.
(Other is ether.js)

The author ChainSafe https://chainsafe.io/ says:

> The only blockchain R&D firm with a multi-chain perspective

But I don't see PolkaDot or other blockchains support by web3.js

What is client library for PolkaDot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client library for Polkadot is Polkadot JS: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/

Comment: but documentation is almost empty for that lib :(

Answer (score 0):

Ethers.js [is said](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1759#event-5065684993) to support Polkadot.

Discussion in https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/1800